# How to prevent firebase authentication to set the user if the promise in the then block fails

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I am new to firebase authentication with React Native.

I have two navigation stacks - Auth Stack(contains only auth screens like sign up, sign in) & App stack(contains home screen).

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user: any) => {
    setUser(user);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={fxTheme}>
      {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

I have written a function for Google Sign in.

```
await auth()
      .signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
      .then(async fUser => {
         try{
           const dbUser = await saveDb(fUser)
         }
         catch(e) {
            // if any errors don't set the user in firebase
         }
      })
      .catch(error => {
           // do something
      });
```

**Actual**: If any errors in saving data to DB in `then` block of `auth().signInWithCredential()`, it is setting the user and redirecting to `<AppStack/>`

**Expected**: If any errors in saving data to DB in `then` block of `auth().signInWithCredential()`, we shouldn't set the user and do not redirect to `<AppStack/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix async / await syntax with traditional then / catch syntax. It's never needed. It's wrong and makes your code hard to read.

Prefer this approach:

```js
try {
  const fUser = await auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
  const dbUser = await saveDb(fUser);
} catch(e) {
  // error handling
}
```

Now about your situation. What makes it hard is that you need to perform an async task with the db after you are already logged in Firebase.

You need to enable communication between your auth component and your app. You can use a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for this, that will store your user after full authentication.

## Inside your auth context

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

const onAuthStateChanged = (firebaseUser: any) => {
  if (!firebaseUser) {
    setUser(null);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
  return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
}, []);
```

## Inside your app stack

```js
const { user } = useContext();

return (
  <NavigationContainer theme={fxTheme}>
    {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

## Inside your auth stack

```js
const { user, setUser } = useContext();

try {
  const userCredential = await auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
  const dbUser = await saveDb(userCredential);
  setUser(userCredential.user);
} catch(e) {
  setUser(null);
}
```